# How can I change for automated-backup retention count in AlloyDB?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-alloydb

I tried to change for automated-backup retention count by gcloud command below.

```
gcloud alloydb clusters update XXXXXXXX\
    --automated-backup-days-of-week="MONDAY,TUESDAY,WEDNESDAY,THURSDAY,FRIDAY,SATURDAY,SUNDAY" \
    --automated-backup-start-times="18:00,19:00,20:00,21:00,22:00" \
    **--automated-backup-retention-count=2** \
    --region="XXXXXXXX \
    --project="XXXXXXXX"
```

I thought the backup would only leave 2 data, but all data was not deleted.
By the way, I was able to change the time to get the backup.
Therefore, the gcloud command is successful.

I read the documents for gcloud cmmand below.
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alloydb/clusters/update

My result below.
12/27 Five backups remain.
12/28 Five backups remain.
12/29 Five backups remain.
12/30 Five backups remain.
12/31 Five backups remain.
1/1 Five backups remain.
1/2 Five backups remain.
1/3 Five backups remain.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Dbr3.png)

Comment: I'm diggin into this with our eng team to confirm. Stay tuned.

Answer (score 0):

Huge apologies, but you've hit a (now) known bug. We're tracking to fix it shortly, but the issue is with the count limited backups. The time-limited backups still work.

There's actually two issues currently. The first is that the count flag doesn't reduce the number of backups. The SECOND bug is that garbage collection is also not working as intended currently.

Backups older than their retention period might still appear when you view your project’s backups. Expired backups don't incur storage costs, but they are subject to automatic deletion. If you need to delete backups before the system deletes them, you can manually delete your backups at any time.

In order to ensure that you’re not incorrectly charged during this period, we will issue billing corrections for your impacted projects to negate or refund backup charges. If you see charges that aren't corrected, please reach out to support and we can get it sorted out.